# Tex Live Utility (Mac Os X): language problem

Tags: texlive, mac, updating

I just made a fresh install of OS X Mavericks and got Tex Live Utility through their Google Code website. The strange thing is that it is in chinese language. And I can't find the button to change it. Anyone else having this problem? Or anybody who knows where to change the language?

Comment: Did you install MacTeX with the Mac extras?  If so, you should have a copy of TeX Live Utility in the TeX folder inside your Applications folder.  Does that one have the language problem too?

Comment: In the Language and Region system preference, there should be a list of preferred languages. If an application isn't localized for a particular language, then it will choose the next one on the list.  Check that the list you have makes sense for you.

Comment: Thanks, the language / region preferences did it. Is that new in Mavericks? Can't remember that I had that problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Language and Region system preference there should be a list of preferred languages. You can add or delete languages as makes sense for you. If a particular application isn't localized for the main language you have chosen, it will go down the list of languages until it finds a language for which it *is* localized.  Make sure that the list of languages in your preferences makes sense for you.

[image: Language and Region preference]

This preference has changed in Mavericks, so it's possible that the issue never came up before.